# Is it valid to define function(json) and if yes what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, json, function

```
    $.getJSON(link,function(json)
       {
            if( json.length> 0)
       {

document.form_reserve.action ="http://localhost/ReserveRoomsBackend.php?        

bldg_number="+json[0].bldg_number +" & room_number="+json[0].room_number;
        document.getElementById("form_reserve").style.display = "block";
    }
             else
       {
           document.getElementById("label").style.display = "block";
       }

alert("inside json finction" + json.length+"  "+json[0].room_number+"   "+json

[0].bldg_number);
        }); //.getJSON

    }//doAjaxPost
```

Answer (score 2):

it's just an argument.  The function expects ONE argument which is a JS object that jQuery has evaluated from a JSON string.

You're potentially confused by the fact that the `{` is on the next line, but it's the same as:

```
function(whatever){
```

Comment: Actually the argument passed is a JavaScript object... ;)

Comment: @cwolves: No. Correct usage of terminology is important when communicating with other people: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @cwolves It's not about happiness, it's about the truth. Be open to learn new things from other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function $.getJSON (part of jQuery I guess) with an anonymous function as second parameter/argument (as a callback in this situation). Those anonymous functions are like "normal" functions, they just don't have a name and since you pass this function to getJSON as a reference, jQuery is able to call your function. So, yes it's valid. If this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, json is a parameter passed to a function object, so yeah it's fine (although it's not very representative of the objects content) - it could be named anything.

In this case it could be called "rooms", and you would could call rooms[0].room_number instead of json[0].room_number.

For example, in this case "message" is the name of the parameter:

```
showAlertDialog("This an example");

function showAlertDialog(message) {
    alert("Your message was:" + message);
}
```

"json" is often used as the name for the response object in jQuery examples (as it is in your case here).